# Javascript JSON syntax

Tags: javascript

HI I am trying to create a JSON file in which I want to store some data for different files. The problem is I cannot figure the correct syntax. Here is what I have so far:

```
var object = {
    "id-1" :[
                {
                    "type":"Corporate Website",
                    "tech":"HTML" ,"CSS" , "Javascript/jQuery"

                }
            ], 
    "id-2" :[

             ]
}
```

I seem to be getting an error at "tech".If that is not corect how can I enumarate multiple elements?I am sorry for the noob question I have been using javascript for a short period of time and I am still very confused with  the language.

Comment: Note that what you have is a JavaScript object literal, not JSON. JSON is just a text format that happens to be a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: FYI if you have trouble with javascript syntax check out [jslint.com](http://jslint.com/) and with JSON: [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{
"id-1": [
    {
        "type": "Corporate Website",
        "tech": [
            "HTML",
            "CSS",
            "Javascript/jQuery"
        ]
    }
],
"id-2": []
}
```

Note the array like syntax for "tech".

Comment: If they're not necessary, you could also lose the additional square brackets around the value corresponding to the key "id-1". These turn it into an array of size one. They are unnecessary in the example shown, unless you need more values assigned to some ids.

Answer (score 5):

Tech should be an array (enclosed in square brackets):

```
"tech": ["HTML", "CSS", "Javascript/jQuery"]
```

Source:

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).

- http://www.json.org/